# including job title to contacts page

Tags: fields

There is a field called title already but I cannot get this to be included as a field on the contact information page. I have added it to the contact layout page and saved it but still it doesn't appear. I know I could create a custom field and this would appear but I would like to get to the bottom of how to add existing fields to be included when I am adding a new contact.

Thanks
The first picture is the add new contact screen, this is where I would like the field title to appear. The second image is the contact layout page (created through customise, contacts page) that I have edited to include the title as a field. This has not made any difference. I basically want to add the field title (already exists) to the contacts page
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "Contact Information" page versus the "Contact layout". Is this a publisher action layout maybe? Can you post photos, or maybe layout out the specific steps the user is going through? I think with a bit more detail it could be made more clear and you'll find an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming when you say "contact information page" you are referring to the contact detail page.  Make sure the field is visible to your profile.  Check field level security.

Also if you have many page layouts, make sure you've added the field to the page layout that is assigned to your profile.

Comment: Thanks title was unchecked in the Contact Field-Level Security for profile!

Comment: As simple as it is, we've all done it!  Glad I could contribute!